# Custom post-type in root directory, blog posts in subdirectory

Tags: custom-post-types, url-rewriting, blog

I have a website with one custom post type as well as a blog.

For the custom post type I would like to have the slug as root, like so

```
http://domain.com/<title>
```

And the blog post I would like to display under /blog, like so

```
http://domain.com/blog/<title>
```

I've managed to "minimize" the custom post type's urls by using these two functions:

```
add_filter( 'post_type_link', function($post_link, $post, $leavename) {
    if('custom' == $post->post_type && 'publish' == $post->post_status) {
        $post_link = str_replace( '/' . $post->post_type . '/', '/', $post_link);
        return $post_link;
    }

    return $post_link;

}, 10, 3 );
```

and

```
add_action('pre_get_posts', function($query) {
    if ( ! $query->is_main_query() || 3 != count( $query->query ) || ! isset( $query->query['page'] ) ) {
        return;
    }

    if ( ! empty( $query->query['name'] ) ) {
        $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'post', 'custom', 'page' ) );
    }
});
```

However, I have not managed to move my blog posts to /blog.

I've tried to set the permalink structure to

```
/blog/%postname%/
```

and the custom post type's rewrite to

```
'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'custom', 'with_front' => false)
```

However, this does not produce the desired effect (domain.com/title). Instead, the "custom" slug is now part of the url again. Manually removing it (domain.com/title) produces a 404.

Comment: Could you explain the conditions you use in `pre_get_posts` function? Especially the one with `3 != ...`?

Comment: I actually did not write it myself, but found it somewhere. The `3 != ` part I don't understand myself.

Comment: OK. I think it's very specific for given case...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

moving blog posts to `/blog/` is pretty easy and you can use WordPress settings to do that - no coding needed.

[image]

The problem you will have though is that after moving posts, your CPT URL structure will conflict with URL structure of pages - so you'll have to modify your `pre_get_posts` function.

As for your `post_type_link` you can simplify it a lot (if it is not hierarchical... is it?):

```
add_filter( 'post_type_link', function($post_link, $post, $leavename) {
    if ('custom' == $post->post_type && 'publish' == $post->post_status) {
        $post_link = site_url('/') . $post->post_name .'/';
    }

    return $post_link;

}, 10, 3 );
```

And I also wouldn't use `pre_get_posts` for selecting proper posts. Using `parse_request` is a lot easier for this task and it allows you to prevent 404 errors a lot easier.

```
add_action( 'parse_request', function ( $wp ) {
    if ( ! is_admin() ) {
        if ( array_key_exists('error', $wp->query_vars) && '404' == $wp->query_vars['error'] ) {
            $custom_post = get_page_by_path( $wp->request, OBJECT, 'CUSTOM' );

            if ( $custom_post instanceof WP_Post ) {
                unset( $wp->query_vars['error'] );
                $wp->query_vars['page'] = '';
                $wp->query_vars['CUSTOM'] = $wp->query_vars['name'] = $wp->request;
                $wp->query_vars['post_type'] = 'CUSTOM';
            }            
        }
    }

    return $wp;
} );
```

Comment: Krzysiek, this I have done already. However, together with the code above which is necessary for removing the /custom/ from the custom post type's url, it does not work. I end up with `/blog/title` and `/custom/title` which is not what I want (for the custom post type, I only want `/title`).

Comment: Sorry, I missed the text below the screenshot. In what way do I need to modify the code in `pre_get_posts` in order to avoid the conflict?

Comment: Personally I wouldn't use `pre_get_posts` for this. `parse_request` is a little bit earlier and better - it's easier to prevent 404 errors, when you're using it.

Comment: Ok, that's good to know, thanks! I tried it with `parse_request`, however I still get the  404.

Comment: I've updated my answer with parse_request function. Remember to change CUSTOM to your CPT slug.

Comment: Krzysiek, this is excellent. It works perfectly, thanks! There is a typo in your code: `quer_vars` which should be `query_vars`, but StackExchange won't let me fix it, because the fix is shorter than 6 chars... In any case, thanks!

Comment: @FSH ahhh, right - good catch with that typo. I think I’ve fixed it :)